# Getting error "Error inflating class SwitchPreference" in android

Tags: android

I have created a setting activity in android. I'm using this below code in it.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends SherlockPreferenceActivity implements  OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, OnPreferenceClickListener {

QuoteOfTheDayAlarmManager alert;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    alert = new QuoteOfTheDayAlert();
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences); 
    this.updateTimeSummary(this.findPreference("qotd_notification_time"), 
            super.getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().getInt("qotd_notification_time.hour", 8),
            super.getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().getInt("qotd_notification_time.minute", 0),
            super.getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().getBoolean("qotd_show_notification", false));

    this.findPreference("share_settings_intent").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs, String key) {


    if (key.equals("qotd_show_notification")) {
        if (sharedPrefs.getBoolean("qotd_show_notification", false)) {
            alert.setAlarm(this.getBaseContext());
        } else {
            alert.cancelAlarm(this.getBaseContext());
        }
    } else if (key.equals("qotd_notification_time.hour") ||
               key.equals("qotd_notification_time.minute")) {
        this.updateTimeSummary(this.findPreference("qotd_notification_time"), 
                sharedPrefs.getInt("qotd_notification_time.hour", 8),
                sharedPrefs.getInt("qotd_notification_time.minute", 0),
                sharedPrefs.getBoolean("qotd_show_notification", false));
    } 

}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    super.getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    this.findPreference("share_settings_intent").setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();        
    super.getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}   

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
{    
    switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
        finish(); 
        break;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
    return true;
}       



@Override
public void finish() {
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("ComingFrom", "Settings");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    super.finish();
}



/**
 * Nice display of the hour values
 * @param pref
 * @param hour
 * @param minute
 */
private void updateTimeSummary(Preference pref, int hour, int minute, boolean alertActive) {
    TimePreference timePref = (TimePreference)pref;
    String ampmFlag = (hour > 11) ? "PM" : "AM";
    String minuteString = (minute < 10) ? "0" + String.valueOf(minute) : String.valueOf(minute);
    String hourString = (hour > 12) ? String.valueOf(hour-12) : String.valueOf(hour);
    timePref.setSummary(String.format("%s:%s %s", hourString, minuteString, ampmFlag));
    //Also cancel and reset the alarm
    alert.cancelAlarm(this.getBaseContext());
    if (alertActive) { alert.setAlarm(this.getBaseContext()); }
}



@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference pref) {
    if (pref.getKey().equals("share_settings_intent")) {

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Value Investor Wisdom");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "I found this great app about Value Investing on Google Play!  Check it out: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dcallaghan.valueinvestorwisdom");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

    }
    return true;
}
```

}

This activity is running in android version above 2.3.x. But when i run this in 2.3.x i get error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.evilsofts.friendshipandlove/com.evilsofts.friendshipandlove.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class SwitchPreference
```

Can anyone help me why i'm getting this error in android 2.3.x ? Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`SwitchPreference` was introduces with the `API level 14`. It is not available with the support library, so you can not use it in Android 2.3.x.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/SwitchPreference.html) you can find the documentation for `SwitchPreference`

Comment: Thank you for replying sir :) If i want to run this in 2.3.x then what should i use?

Comment: you can try to backport it. The source code is available online